# have heard or heard in that case

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Shall I say

> I (**heard/have heard**) of you through a friend. He wrote to me and
>   recommended me to listen to your band.

I think past simple for *hear* is better because I remember clearly when I received the letter and it belongs to the past. But what puzzled me is that it is also connected to the present. I know the band now so in fact maybe both are correct.

Comment: *I heard* implies that the action of *hearing* is finished. *I've heard* also implies a finished action, but in some way it brings a result to the present.

Comment: so have heard is better in my sentence

Comment: As a short action with no relevance in the present, yes.

Comment: **through a friend** is more idiomatic than than **because of a friend**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=through+a+friend%2C+because+of+a+friend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrough%20a%20friend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecause%20of%20a%20friend%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine. "I heard of you through a friend" is more idiomatic in this context, to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker of American English, I can say that I agree with Colin.

'I *heard* of you through a friend...'

The action *to hear* happened at some indefinite time in the *past*. Of course the past action of *hearing* still has a "connection" to present time, but not grammatically. You make it clear that your past hearing is still relevant to the present by the very fact you are presently communicating with the band.

Also, the following sounds much better for your second sentence:

'He wrote to me and recommended that I listen to your band.'

or

'He wrote to me and recommended to me to listen to your band.'

This answer is written from the perspective of American English. A speaker of British English may have a different preference.